# Javaxcript regex metacharacter not working inside brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to construct a javascript function to replace one classname with another one. When I use a function like

```
function foo(bar)
{
    bar.className=bar.className.replace(/\bone/, "two");
}​
```

on a markup like

```
<div class="one" onclick="foo(this)"></div>​
```

it correctly finds and replaces `one` with `two`. But when I'm using brackets to include other characters which may precede `one`, `\b` fails to recognize the beginning of the string, and gives no matches. Example:

```
function foo(bar)
{
    bar.className=bar.className.replace(/[\b\s]one/, "two");
}​
```

doesn't work. Not even `/[\b]one/` will work.

See http://jsfiddle.net/E4ph5/ to see it in action. What am I doing wrong? (In the fiddle, if you remove the brackets, the script works correctly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets define a character class. Inside such a class markers such as `\b` (word boundary) do not work as they do not make sense there.

`/\bone/` is fine in your case anyway - whitespace is also a word boundary: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/Z8HTE/ - you could improve it by using `/\bone\b/` to avoid matching e.g. `class="onetwothree"`